# Grails - String to date conversion

Tags: date, grails

I'm trying to convert a string to a date and I'm able to do it when my string is in this format: `14/09/2016` or `09-14-2016`, etc. using the `new Date().parse('dd/MM/yyyy', myDateString)` method. But now I have a string that looks like this: `14 September 2016`. So what I want to know is what format do I give the parse method to make this work. `new Date().parse('/*what goes here?*/', myDateString)`. Also will this method even work?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Date.parse`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#parse(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) is a wrapper for [`SimpleDateFormat.parse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)), so that's where you'll want to look to find an appropriate format string. In the case of "14 September 2016", your format string would look like this: "dd MMM yyyy".

The key part for parsing this string is "MMM". From the docs:

> Month: If the number of pattern letters is 3 or more, the month is
>   interpreted as text; otherwise, it is interpreted as a number.